# How to align table with other table components on same page

Tags: html, css, angular

I’m trying to get the table underlined in the image below to line up with the ‘Notifications’ table that is to the right of it and also line up with the ‘Welcome’ table below up. So it basically aligns pushed over to the left with ‘Welcome’ and top and bottom line up with 'Notifications to the right of it. Sorry the lines aren’t drawn perfectly but you can see how I want it aligned. Basically I want to move the outlined ‘Account Overview’ table up and over to the left. Drew lines to show in the image.

[image]

**html**

```
<div class="sdps-is-relative badge-example-outline sdps-p-around_medium sdps-m- 
   around_medium">
   <sdps-badge
     sdps-id="spdb-promotional-beta-overlay"
      type="promotional"
      status-text="Beta"
      promotional-type="beta"
      sr-label-prefix="You have got"
      sr-label-suffix="notifications"
      is-overlay
   >
 </sdps-badge>
<div class="ao-text-header">Account Overview has a new look</div>
  You can view your retirement accounts below, or go back to the classic experience.
</div>
<sdps-panel sdps-id="account-overview-panel-personalperformance">
 <div class="SSOManageAccount modalInject">
  <div slot="modal-body" appModalContent>
     <div>We want to let you know you’ll be accessing schwabdeferredcompensation.com, a 
 third-party website. By clicking continue below, you are requesting to open a new page. 
 </div>
</div>
<div slot="modal-footer" appModalFooter>
    <div class="rps__d-flex rps__align-items-center SSOManageAccountFooter">
        <div class="rps__flex-grow-1 rps__align-self-end">(0823-3U5E)</div>
        <sdps-button class="sdps-m-left_medium no-margin" variation="secondary"
            sdps-id="btn-manage-external-account" 
    (sdpsClick)="modalContent.actions.secondary.action()"
            [sdpsAriaLabel]="modalContent.actions.secondary.ariaLabel"> 
   {{modalContent.actions.secondary.label}}</sdps-button>
        <sdps-button class="sdps-m-left_medium no-margin" variation="primary"
            sdps-id="btn-manage-external-account" 
     (sdpsClick)="modalContent.actions.primary.action()"
            [sdpsAriaLabel]="modalContent.actions.primary.ariaLabel"> 
    {{modalContent.actions.primary.label}}</sdps-button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div #loadable>
 <app-welcome></app-welcome>
 <div class="sdps-row">
    <app-balance></app-balance>
</div>
<sdps-button class="sdps-m-left_medium no-margin top-margin" variation="secondary" sdps- 
   id="btn-manage-external-account"
    (sdpsClick)="openModal()"
    [sdpsAriaLabel]="modalContent.actions.primary.ariaLabel">{{displayText}}</sdps- 
button>
  </div>
</sdps-panel>
```

**css**

```
@import "lib/scss/variables.scss";

.rps__balance-graph {
  &.loading {
     min-height: 274px;
 }
}
.no-margin {
 margin-left: 0!important;
 }

.top-margin {
 margin-top: 20px!important;
 }

.SSOManageAccountFooter {
& sdps-button:not(:last-child) {
   margin-right: 20px;
 }

 & *:nth-child(1) {
   order: 1;
 }

& *:nth-child(2) {
 order: 2;
 }

& *:nth-child(3) {
   order: 3;
  }
 }

@media (max-width: $tablet-portrait-min) {
 .SSOManageAccountFooter {
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  & > *:not(:last-child) {
    margin-top: 24px;
 }

& *:nth-child(1) {
    order: 3;
}

& *:nth-child(2) {
    order: 2;
}

& *:nth-child(3) {
    order: 1;
}

& sdps-button {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;

    &::ng-deep > button {
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 0;
       }
     }
   }
  }

.badge-example-outline {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #cbd1d6;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
  position: relative;
 }

.ao-text-header {
 font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 font-family: CharlesModern-Medium,CharlesModern-Regular,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;   
}
```

Comment: I would create a container `section` or `div`, put all your inner containers inside and use `display: grid`

Answer (score 1):

I think the `sdps-badge` component has some margin that affects the parent element.
besides you can debug in `class="sdps-is-relative"` and other classes in the parent using the chrome inspect Element tab.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).